# What is the format expected by QGIS for Latitude/Longitude in DMS?

Tags: qgis, csv, latitude-longitude, import, degrees-minutes-seconds

I have been struggling with a CSV file I need to import into QGIS 2.2.0 (on Windows 7).

The coordinates are in this format:

```
LATITUDE  LONGITUDE
424605    861204
395222    861206
303051    861219
32155     861220
395541    861229
425119    861242
```

Latitude and Longitude are in units of degrees, minutes and seconds according to the person who provided the data.

I tried different formats (placing commas, dots, ', ", etc at different places) to import this dataset into QGIS, checking the "DMS coordinates" box in the "Create a layer form Delimited Text File". I always had a Delimited text file error message.

What is the format expected by QGIS for Latitude/Longitude in DMS?

Comment: I'm not sure it can import DMS, you may have to convert them to decimal degrees.

Comment: Guesses-> degrees° minutes' seconds"
But conversion is easy to Decimal Degrees. D+m/60+s/3600

Comment: My search turned up that as long as you check that DMS box the format expected is very general - Three numbers separated by some character(s). ##°##'##" or ##'##'## should work. Commas might not work, as they are often field delimiters. Periods/dots would also potentially indicate a decimal (as it supposedly can take degree-decimal minute). Can you try ##-##-## and see if that works? The issue may also be your field delimiting character - if a tab try a comma or vice-versa.

Comment: Examples of valid formats can be found in the [test data for QGIS](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/tests/testdata/delimitedtext/testdms.csv)

Comment: "32155" is ambiguous -- would it be 32°15'05", 32°01'55" or 03°21'55"?

Comment: Just to note that If you are south of the equator you'll need to add a minus sign to the front of the latitude co-ordinates and ensure your project CRS is WGS84. When importing to QGIS the 'x field' should be set to longitude and the 'y field' to latitude.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the data is really DD MM SS you can just add the data as follows

LAT,LON

42 46 05 N,86 12 04 E

I use spaces to separate DD MM SS and I assume since numbers are positive N,E. Other ways may work but I find this the fastest for me at least since using special characters takes typing time

Comment: Did you mean N,E?

Comment: Ah yes N,E typo since I only ever use N,W in my part of the world

Answer (score 1):

working with QGIS 3.16.4-Hannover, here what worked for me after couple of hours:

```
39°15'44.856"E,21°35'41.815"N
```

for some reason QGIS wasn't able to plot the geometry and only gave a table, in the above notation, limiting your decimals for the seconds -i used python "{.3f}".format(S)- was crucial -not necessary 3 places i tried up to 9 and worked, but the absence of limiting seconds decimals was causing me an error, at first i left the seconds float as it was calculated, that was a problem.
also I uses integers for degrees and minutes.

Answer (score -2):

My friend the format you have given up there is utm which is in metres. It 100% possible to export dms in QGIS as lon as u have well arranged and tick dms check box. So convert utm to dms or dd then export

Comment: It is unlikely that UTM coordinates would not have 6, 7, 8, or 9 in the tens or thousands places.  Given that the values are marked latitude/longitude, and the values are compatible with DMS, and the DMS answer was marked correct, it's probably incorrect to assert that this is UTM data.